# Odoo8 website transfer input value from product page to cart page

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I'm working on project in odoov8. I need to add a field on the product page and then create an order which includes this field.

To be more specific, I have added Start Date field on the product page, I can select a date on it, but when I hit "Add to Cart" and I go to Cart page, product don't have the date I have selected.
I need similar functionality that quantity field has.

Here is the code I used to display the Date field on product page:

```
<template id="product_quantity" inherit_id="website_sale.product">
            <xpath expr="//a[@id='add_to_cart']" position="after">
                <p>
                    <group colspan="2" col="2">
                        <label for="date">Rent Start Date
                            <input type="date" string="Rent Start Date"  class="form-control" name="start_date" id="start_date"  data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch"  />
                        
                        </label>
                    </group>
                </p>
            </xpath>
    </template>
```

And here is how it looks:
[image: Date field on product page]

Also, I'm interested in a way to initialize this field with current date.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the model `sale.order` and add a new field, in your case call it maybe `start_date`, but make sure it does not already exist on `sale.order`.

You can [see an example of how to define such a field in the original Odoo v8 repo here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale/sale.py#L205). You can then set a default value for that field, [see for example here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale/sale.py#L256).

If I recall correctly, the `Add to cart` button triggers the controller at the route `'/shop/cart/cart_update'`, so you will have to [extend the method `cart_update`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L347) and update the sale order according to your needs.

I would suggest you extend the method, do a `super` call [as it is for example done here](https://github.com/OCA/e-commerce/blob/8.0/website_sale_cart_preview/controllers/main.py#L13) (this is just an example in case you have never done this, of course you need to adjust it) and save the return value for super in a variable, e.g. `res = super(...)`.

After the `super` you change the sale order (you need to  fetch it somehow, either you check if the sale order is already available in `res.qcontext` (probably will not since the [parent returns a redirect](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L350)), or you fetch it via `request.website.sale_get_order()` [which can be seen here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L325).

After you update the sale order, you finally `return res`.

Something along these lines should do it:

```
@http.route()
def cart_update(self, product_id, add_qty=1, set_qty=0, **kw):
    res = super(WebsiteSale, self).cart_update(product_id,
                                               add_qty, set_qty, **kw)
    order = request.website.sale_get_order()
    # update your order now 
    # ... 

    # finally return 
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: @Dima You are welcome. If you find the answer useful, you can accept it by clicking on the tick next to it.